# Making batch-file for Gnuplot

Tags: batch

How can I make a batch file with a series of commandos for Gnuplot, and then execute it in Gnuplot? For example: defining a function, setting the x- and y-axis settings, setting an output so when I run Gnuplot and execute this file, I immediately got my graph. 
Thanks for reading in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Below is an excerpt from http://people.duke.edu/~hpgavin/gnuplot.html:

> **6. SCRIPT FILES**
>
> Sometimes, several commands are typed to create a particular plot, and
>   it is easy to make a typographical error when entering a command. To
>   stream- line your plotting operations, several Gnuplot commands may be
>   combined into a single script file. For example, the following file
>   will create a customized display of the force-deflection data:
>
> ```
>   # Gnuplot script file for plotting data in file "force.dat"
>   # This file is called   force.p
>   set   autoscale                        # scale axes automatically
>   unset log                              # remove any log-scaling
>   unset label                            # remove any previous labels
>   set xtic auto                          # set xtics automatically
>   set ytic auto                          # set ytics automatically
>   set title "Force Deflection Data for a Beam and a Column"
>   set xlabel "Deflection (meters)"
>   set ylabel "Force (kN)"
>   set key 0.01,100
>   set label "Yield Point" at 0.003,260
>   set arrow from 0.0028,250 to 0.003,280
>   set xr [0.0:0.022]
>   set yr [0:325]
>   plot    "force.dat" using 1:2 title 'Column' with linespoints , \
>         "force.dat" using 1:3 title 'Beam' with points
> ```
>
> Then the total plot can be generated with the command: `gnuplot> load
>   'force.p'`

The file `force.dat` looks something like:

```
  # This file is called   force.dat
  # Force-Deflection data for a beam and a bar
  # Deflection    Col-Force       Beam-Force 
  0.000              0              0    
  0.001            104             51
  0.002            202            101
  0.003            298            148
  0.0031           290            149
  0.004            289            201
  0.0041           291            209
  0.005            310            250
  0.010            311            260
  0.020            280            240
```

Please look at the [source](http://people.duke.edu/~hpgavin/gnuplot.html) for further information and a much better explanation.